What do the hexadecimal numbers represent on the ls output of the /dev directory?
When I run ls -l /dev on my Ubuntu, I get output like this:
$ ls -l /dev
total 0
crw-r--r-- 1 root root     10, 235 Aug 24 16:36 autofs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root         340 Aug 24 16:40 block
crw------- 1 root root     10, 234 Aug 24 16:36 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        2660 Aug 24 16:37 char

The 10, 235 in the 5th column shows the major and minor numbers that specifies which device driver is used to manage the file.
When I run the same command on macOS, I get this output:
% ls -l /dev
total 1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root       wheel     0x16000000 14 Aug 22:16 aes_0
crw-------  1 root       wheel     0x15000001 14 Aug 22:16 afsc_type5
brw-------  1 root       operator   0x2000000 24 Aug 19:39 apfs-raw-device.2.0
crw-------  1 root       wheel      0xb000001 14 Aug 22:16 auditpipe

Instead of the major/minor numbers, I get a single hexadecimal number. My question is - what do those hexadecimal number represent?

What I tried/researched

There are different files that shares the same hexadecimal. So it doesn't appear to represent the major/minor numbers, as, from what I understand, that combination should be unique?
brw-r-----  1 root       operator   0x1000001 14 Aug 22:16 disk0s1
crw-r-----  1 root       operator   0x1000001 14 Aug 22:16 rdisk0s1


ChatGPT tries to convince me that the hexadecimal number is a packed format for the major and minor numbers, but was not being very clear about how to interpret it. If I split the 32-bit into halves and interpret the first 16 bits as major and last 16 bits as minor, the major number seems unusally large (e.g. 0x1d000000 gives 7424 as the major number.

Installing the coreutils package on my Mac and using the ls there gave me the familiar major/minor pairs.
$ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/coreutils/9.5/libexec/gnubin/ls -l /dev
total 1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root      wheel    22,    0 Aug 14 22:16 aes_0
crw------- 1 root      wheel    21,    1 Aug 14 22:16 afsc_type5
brw------- 1 root      operator  2,    0 Aug 24 21:02 apfs-raw-device.2.0
crw------- 1 root      wheel    11,    1 Aug 14 22:16 auditpipe
...
brw-r----- 1 root      operator  1,    1 Aug 14 22:16 disk0s1
...
crw-r----- 1 root      operator  1,    1 Aug 14 22:16 rdisk0s1




About point 1 - both devices have same ID but one of them is CHAR device, another is BLOCK (check the first letters of the lines)

What do you get if you install GNU coreutils and use that ls instead?

From the macOS ls(1) manual: "If the file is a character special or block special file, the device number for the file is displayed in the size field."

@Kusalananda Is the 'device number' equivalent to the major/minor number pairs? Is this just a matter of how it is displayed? Some display as major/minor pair, some use a single device number?
From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-3159/fgove/index.html
"A device number identifies a particular device and minor node in the device tree. Each device has a major number and a minor number. A device number is a major,minor pair. A long file listing shows the device number in the column where file sizes are usually listed."

@muru I have updated my question with the output from coreutil's ls. I think I now understand the hexadecimal is a combination of the major and minor numbers, but it's not a 32-bit number with a 16/16 split. Rather, it's a 24-bit number where the first 8 bits are used for the major number, and the last 16 bit is used for the minor number.

Strictly speaking, device numbers do not need to be unique, even within the b and c realms.  I can do mknod foo c 17 42 and mknod bar c 17 42, and I will have two names for the same device.  Similar to a link, but two separate i-nodes; so, for example, they can have different owners and permissions.

If we're to believe the major(), minor(), makedev() macros at https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/xnu-10063.141.1/bsd/sys/types.h#L161 in the XNU sources that Apple makes available, the minor number is stored in the lowest 24 bits of the st_rdev field in the structure returned by lstat(), and major number in the highest 8 bits (the rest, for a total of 32 bits).
That's consistent with the results you get with macos' and GNU's ls:
0x16000000 == makedev(22, 0)
0x15000001 == makedev(21, 1)

0x16000000 and 0x15000001 being just the raw value of st_rdev in hexadecimal.
Note that in any case, the format of the "device info" field in ls -l output is left "implementation defined" by POSIX. While most other systems show major and minor separately, the format in which they do vary from implementation to implementation, some separating into two fields like GNU ls, some not, or not-always, some with 0-padding... One of the many reasons it's almost impossible to parse the output of ls reliably (and portably).
